# How can I participate on Echolink with my Android phone?

Tags: echolink

I want to use my Android mobile phone to send and receive over Echolink, like if I was using an amateur radio station. How can I do that?

I'm a SWL and only plan to listen until I get my license, and my brother does have a valid amateur radio license.

Comment: You should be aware that **without a valid amateur radio license, or under the supervision of a properly licensed control operator, you are not allowed to transmit on the amateur radio bands.** This is a major reason why [to get access to Echolink, you must provide proof of a valid amateur radio license](http://www.echolink.org/validation/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is at least one app on the Google app store which will connect to echolink, which can be found here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.echolink.android

There are other apps that may also connect to Echolink, or are otherwise useful for Echolink users:

https://play.google.com/store/search?q=echolink&c=apps